# How java create objects implicitly? Like in case of String class

Tags: java, string, objectinstantiation

I can't understand how an object is created implicitly.

Example:

```
String s = "implicit instantiation";
```

Can I make my own class whose objects can be created implicitly?

Comment: In short: you can't.

Comment: `String` is a special object that has some syntactic sugar around it - string literals, concatenation operator, ability to be used in `switch` cases. Only Strings have that capability (arrays also have "literals").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, String instantiation is handled implicitly by the compiler. Only the String and Array classes have this property.

```
String greeting = "Hello world!";
char[] helloArray = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.' };
```

[Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) allows you to implicitly instantiate objects of primitive wrapper types, but that's also a special case handled by the compiler. You can't create your own classes with this ability.

```
Boolean b = false;
Integer i = 0;
Double pi = 3.1416;
```

Comment: can't we do `Integer i = 5` too ?

Comment: @Shashwat Oh yes, let me add that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you just can not do that!

opposite to C or C++ you can not overload any operator in java language, so there is no possible way to do something like

```
Foo myFoo = 1
```

in the case of the string class:

```
String s = "implicit instantiation"
```

that is sugar sintax for the developers, behind the scenes is the compiler doing the "dirty" work and doing something like (remember there is a string pool):

```
String s = new String("implicit instantiation")
```

---

The same applies for some other Types like Arrays, or wrapper for numbers...

Answer (score 0):

For every instance of an object you need a Constructor and a constructor its a a special method for construct and initialize methods. Example:

```
String s;  // Is not initialized and it's nos constructed.
```

So how do you construct a new object in java? Easy with the `new operator` you create a New Object!

```
s = new String("qwe"); // New object constructed
```

But here is something that a lot of newbies get confussed. Why i can do this:

```
String s= "asdfasd;"
```

Because `String` is a special case in Java and you don't need to add a `new operator` like all the primitive variables that are classes. Example:

```
Integer i = 3; 
Double d = 3.3d;
```

and So on.